# Assign values to registers and add / subtract them

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am completely lost with this, any help on how can I complete the code below

Using the AddTwo program below I need to program that calculates the following expression, using registers: varA = (varA + varB) − (varC + varD),
where varA, varB, etc., are variables. Assign integer values to
the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers for the aforementioned variables. (Meaning,
you may hardcode the inputs

Code:

```
; AddTwoSum_64.asm - Chapter 3 example.

ExitProcess proto

.data
sum qword 0

.code
main proc
    mov rax,5
    add rax,6
    mov   sum,rax
    mov   ecx,0
    call  ExitProcess

main endp
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Start with the parts you know how to do.  For example "Assign integer values to the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX".  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd call this an "answer," but I can't fit what I want to say in a comment.

Let's look at the code you've got, step by step.

```
mov eax,varA
```

So, at this point, eax contains 5

```
add    eax,varB
```

Now we are adding 3 to eax, giving us 8 in eax.  So far so good.

```
mov    ecx,varC
```

This will put 4 in ecx.

```
add    ecx,varD
```

And this will add 1 to ecx, giving us 5 in ecx.

Now, none of the statements to this point have changed any of the values in varA-varD.  They are still at the values they started with.

So, what's left to do?  Looking at your original equation, we've got `varA = (varA + varB) − (varC + varD)`.  So what's left?

If we've done (varA + varB) and stored it in eax, and we've done (varC + varD) and stored it in ecx, then we're (roughly) at varA = eax - ecx.

I'm pretty sure you know how to take eax and `sub`tract ecx, yes?  And if you know how to `mov`e a value from memory into a register (`mov eax, varA`), then you can probably figure out how to move a value from a register back to memory.

So you're very close.  There are 2 other points I might raise.

1. You aren't doing anything with varA to show that your code is working.  Are you supposed to print this out or something?  Run it under a debugger?  Or what?
2. The instructions you posted directed you to *"Assign integer values to the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers for the aforementioned variables"* and that's not quite what you have done.  You have read the values from memory (which I might argue is the better plan) instead of just doing:

.

```
mov eax, 5
mov ebx, 3
mov ecx, 4
mov edx, 1
```

Then doing the adds and subtracts from there.  Instructors can be picky about not exactly following instructions, so you might want to re-work this.